# Initialising and using a global table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm very new to Lua and I'm trying to globally initialise a table at the very start of my program. At the top, I have:

```
storage = {}
```

Then, I want to iterate over elements in this table inside functions in the same file. One example is:

```
local output
for item in storage do
    output = output .. item
end
return output
```

In this case, I get:

```
attempt to call a nil value
```

On the line beginning with `for`.

I have also tried printing out `storage[1]`. In this case I get:

```
attempt to index local 'storage' (a nil value)
```

Could someone please explain in simple terms what could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you initializing that `storage` variable in the same file as the code trying to use it? If not are you hitting module boundaries? What environment are you using lua in?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the syntax for the for-loop. It expects three values: A callable, a context, and a start key. `pairs` returns such...

Comment: It's initialised in the same file. It's within a custom framework but I've copied the structure exactly. I changed it to a 3-value for loop and I get `attempt to get length of local 'storage' (a nil value)`

Comment: Paul's answer pretty much sums up the problem. For whatever reason, `storage` isn't given a defined value when you try to iterate over it -- that is what the error is telling you. There's not enough of your script shown to say exactly why that is and the possible causes are numerous. Maybe `storage` got `nil` by something you didn't expect, or `storage` is in a different file that wasn't evaluated before you tried to loop through it, or maybe the function environment got changed, or a tighter `local storage` scope got between them hiding the global one etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing the entire script, but it's clear that `storage` value gets reset somewhere between your initialization and using in `for item in storage do`, because if it keeps the value, you'd get a different error: `attempt to call a table value`.

You need to use `ipairs` or `pairs` function in the loop -- `for key, item in pairs(storage) do` -- but you first need to fix whatever resets the value of `storage`.